# Give color to specific line C# console

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I am working with ASCII art in C# console, and I am wondering if I can give a specific line a different color, or each group of lines a different color. I am yet new with C# so I don't have a good idea how it works. Can you please help me?

I have that draw for an example wich is a flag as background and then two dogs

```
                    static string ShowDogFace()
            {
                return @"
                        
        _______________________________________________________________________________________________________
        |                                                                                                     |
        |                            __     __                                                                |
        |                           / / \__/\ \                                                               |
        |                           \/| /\/\|\/                                                               |
        |                           __||o o||__                                                               |
        |                          / . \__/ .  \                                                              |
        |                         /.  .(__).  . \                                                             |
        |_________________________\ .  /__\ .   /_____________________________________________________________|
        |                          \__/\__/\___/ etf                                                          |
        |                 A                                  A                              A                 |
        |             ___/_\___                          ___/_\___                      ___/_\___             |
        |              ',. ..'                            ',. ..'                        ',. ..'              |
        |              /.'^'.\                            /.'^'.\                        /.'^'.\              |
        |             /'     '\                          /'     '\                      /'     '\             |
        |                                                                                                     |
        |_____________________________________________________________________________________________________|
        |                                             ______________________                                  |
        |                                            /                     /                                  |
        |                             ,-.____,-.    /    Nah am just...   /                                   |
        |                             \_/_  _\_/___/       his son       /                                    |
        |                               )O__O( ___/_____________________/                                     |
        |                              { ( )  }                                                               |
        |                               `_^__'                                                                |
        |_____________________________________________________________________________________________________|



";
            }
```

Comment: How are you currently storing/generating the strings that you print?

Comment: I have updated my code. the drawings are in separate methods and they are called when they should appear